# How to clean circuit damaged by bleach?

Tags: pcb, damage, cleaning

I was trying to remove stains on a fiber optic party tie using bleach, however it seems a small quantity has leaked inside the controller overnight, causing some corrosion and preventing it from powering up. What household products can I use to clean the damage?

[image: damaged circuit]

Comment: Water first, then isopropyl alcohol. Use lots of both. Warning: don't use alcohol first since alcohol and bleach react to create a toxic chemical (chloroform). Use an old toothbrush and throw it away when you are done. Do it in a well-ventilated area just in case some bleach remains when you use the alcohol. Let it dry overnight before powering on again.

Comment: I see. Yesterday I tried cleaning the fabric using alcohol first, then with bleach soon after. I guess that's why I felt a bit dizzy afterwards. 

Comment: Better chloroform than mustard gas.

Comment: Excessive intake   "may adversely affect sexual function and fertility in adult males and females, as well as causing developmental toxicity in the offspring"